# Capture N letters then 2 or three digits

Tags: python, regex

I am to write a regex which captures a string: "N letters followed by 2 or 3 digits", where N is passed as an argument of a function.

What I did is this: `"[a-zA-Z]{" + "{number}".format(number=N) + "}[0,9]{2,3}"` but it's not right. Where's the mistake?

For `N=3`, it should match: `"abc12", "abc123"` but not `"a1", "abc1", "abc1234"`.

Comment: Try `"[a-zA-Z]{" + "{number}".format(number=N) + "}[0-9]{2,3}"`, you are currently not using a range for the number matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second block is only capturing the numbers `0` and `9`, change it to a range:

```
"[a-zA-Z]{%d}[0-9]{2,3}"%N
```

EDIT:
To *not* capture something that doesn't match, you will want to add start and end conditions to your regex. This can be done in a few ways:

## Text Anchors

Start and end line designations if your pattern is to be by itself on a line:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{%d}[0-9]{2,3}$"%N
```

Where `^` represents a start of line and `$` represents end of line

## Designating *Not* matches

You can say to *not* match specific characters after the pattern:

```
"[a-zA-Z]{%d}[0-9]{2,3}[^0-9]+"
```

The `^` inside the brackets will say "Do not match these chars." I'm not familiar enough with lookaheads/lookbacks to give you a good answer using those, but the docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Or, even better, change it to `'\d'`.

Comment: It still captres eg. `aaa1553`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add anchors to your expression:

```
^[a-z]{3}\d{2,3}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8WfcYZ/1/).

---

In general:

```
^[a-z]{n}\d{2,3}$
#     ^^^
```

Comment: @FilipFrey: Consider accepting and/or upvoting an answer if it helped you (green tick and arrows on the left).